# Trying to implement in app purchases, getting error "message sent to deallocated instance" for NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, in-app-purchase

I'm using code from a [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_in_app_purchase.htm) on in app purchases.

The error  `[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance` occurs here:

```
[self purchaseMyProduct:[validProducts objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Here is where `validProducts` is used.

```
-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request
    didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
    int count = [response.products count];
    if (count>0) {


        validProducts = response.products;
        validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
        if (![validProduct.productIdentifier
              isEqualToString:@"facePuppetsSave"]) {

        UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                            initWithTitle:@"Not Available"
                            message:@"No products to purchase"
                            delegate:self
                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                            otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [tmp show];
    }    
}
}
```

I looked at some similar SO questions, which said to add in dealloc

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];

productsRequest.delegate = nil;
[productsRequest cancel];
productsRequest = nil;
```

but nothing changed.

Here are the other methods, in case they are relevant.

```
- (void)fetchAvailableProducts {

   // NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:@"facePuppetsSave"] ,nil];
    productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"facePuppetsSave"]];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];

}

- (BOOL)canMakePurchases
{
    return [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments];
}

- (void)purchaseMyProduct:(SKProduct*)product{
    if ([self canMakePurchases]) {

        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    }
    else{
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:
                                  @"Purchases are disabled in your device" message:nil delegate:
                                  self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alertView show];
    }


}



#pragma mark StoreKit Delegate

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                NSLog(@"Purchasing");
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier
                     isEqualToString:@"facePuppetsSave"]) {
                    NSLog(@"Purchased ");
                    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:
                                              @"Purchase is completed succesfully" message:nil delegate:
                                              self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                    [alertView show];
                }
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                NSLog(@"Restored ");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                NSLog(@"Purchase failed ");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you defining the validProducts property or variable?

Comment: @Mahir You should `retain` the `validProducts` array when assigned from the response. Declare `validProducts` as a `retain`(manual memory management) or `strong`(ARC) property and assign it as `self.validProducts = response.products;`

Comment: I'm guessing the code was written for ARC, because retain fixed it. Do you mind explaining why it's necessary though?

Comment: The `response` object is created and managed by framework. It will not keep the `response` object alive in memory if its not being used(retained) by your code. Since your code needs the `products` array from the `response` object, your code needs to retain it until required. Make sure you release the retained array after use is complete otherwise it will cause memory leak.

Comment: Why are you doing like: `validProducts = response.products;` ?

Comment: That was copied from the tutorial, to be honest